# Is Ansible Tower compatible with the aws_S3 module?

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible, ansible-tower

I have been trying to automate a backup of some server files from a target machine to our S3 instance, but when I run the playbook from Ansible Tower it doesn't seem that the S3 module is able to see any files on the target machine.

AWS authentication is set up with IAM and working properly (authentication check succeeds) and I've confirmed that the Ansible session is successfully signing in to the ubuntu EC2 instance from the log files.

The S3 copy step looks like

```
- name: Push wp conf to archive
  s3:
    bucket: '{{master_config.aws.s3.bucket_name}}'
    object: wp_config.php
    src: '{{master_config.server.wp_config}}'
    mode: put
  become: yes
  become_user: root
```

which works fine.

But when I tried using the aws_s3 instance with the 'remote_src' flag set like so

```
- name: Push wp conf to archive
  aws_s3:
    bucket: '{{master_config.aws.s3.bucket_name}}'
    object: wp_config.php
    src: '{{master_config.server.wp_config}}'
    mode: put
    remote_src: yes
  become: yes
  become_user: root
```

but it produces an error:

```
fatal: [server_address]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find or access '/var/www/html/wp-config.php'"}
```

I came across this discussion in the Github repo for the project which seems to confirm my suspicions: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/40192

If anyone's managed to get this working I'd really appreciate any tips. I've double and triple checked everything else that could be causing an issue, but it seems to be that the s3 / aws_s3 modules are just behaving differently on tower.

I'm running the AMI provided on the tower website at https://www.ansible.com/products/tower/trial

Comment: if your version of tower ships ansible 2.5 (not sure which specific versions) or 2.6 it possibly has this bug yes. Have you tried with the module s3 which seems not affected?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - yup. S3 module works fine for copying remote files. It has some drawbacks vs. aws_s3 though. Any ideas on where to get a more up to date version of tower that won't have the bug?

Comment: You could patch the module yourself on the tower server, that would be ugly but that's work.